# jQuery: Создать div и вывести информацию в него

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть такая. Я жму на кнопку, и происходят следующие действия:

1. Создается div
2. Ему присваивается класс со стилями из css
3. В него перекидываются данные из input/textarea

Все это через jQuery.

Я сделал вот так, но оно не работает

```js
$('#button').click(function() {

    var infoTitle = $('#name').val();
    var infoObject = $('#text').val();

    $('<div>').addClass('point-new');
    $('<div>').addClass('title-new').html(infoTitle);
    $('<div>').addClass('object-new').html(infoObject);
});
```

point-new - родительский, обертка для двух последующих
name - input
text - textarea

p.s. Только разбираюсь в js и jquery, могу не видеть очевидных вещей

Comment: Можно еще `$('body').append("<div class="point-new">" + infoTitle + "</div>")` - сразу вставить строку)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что создавая новые элементы вы не добавляете их на страницу

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#button').click(function() {

    var infoTitle = $('#name').val();
    var infoObject = $('#text').val();

    var parent = $('<div>')   // создали новый элемент
      .addClass('point-new')  // установили ему класс
      .appendTo('body');      // добавили дочерним в элемент body

    $('<div>')                // создали новый элемент
      .addClass('title-new')  // установили ему класс
      .html(infoTitle)        // добавили контент
      .appendTo(parent);      // добавили дочерним в parent

    $('<div>').addClass('object-new').html(infoObject).appendTo(parent);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" type="text"/><br>
<textarea id="text"></textarea><br>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Add"/>
```